# Explanation about column gutter in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone explain in detail what this statement about?

> Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That
>   padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative
>   margin on .rows.
>   - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

I need to understand how the gutter calculation working.

Thanks you ^^

Answer (score 3):

Basically, each column's gutter is defined by padding. So, consider the following example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col1"></div>
    <div class="col1"></div>
    <div class="col1"></div>
</div>
```

If I wanted a 20 pixels gutter on each column, I could define:

```
.col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

This works well, except my first column will also have a 20 pixel gutter, which I don't want. As a result, I could specify `.col1:first-child`, but it's much easier to define a negative left margin on the row, thus cancelling the first column's gutter measurement:

```
.row {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```